# Django DRF: How to get a file response from a post request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to post an image and receive a file containing the OCR result of that image but i m not sure how to do it, i tried to follow the DRF documentations but i m not sure i got it because this is new to me and my first time using django.

```js
 @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def methodes(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.method=='POST':
            serializer=UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()   
                respFile=list(File.objects.filter(id=str(File.objects.latest('created_at'))))
                return Response(respFile)
            return HttpResponse({'message':'error'},status=400)
        elif request.methode=='GET':
                images=Uploads.objects.all()
                serializers=UploadSerializer(images[0],many=False)
                return JsonResponse(serializers.data,safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was the issue or not let me know:
Correction in the above code:

```
elif request.method=='GET':
```

Comment: owh thanks for pointing that out, but no that doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Try to debug all the related code and templates if not resolved the last option is to recreate with proper understanding and care!